# PHP Extension on Windows saved file to different location

Tags: php, windows

I am working on a local server (WAMP/EasyPHP). I am trying to use ActiveX as a PHP extension.

For testing I used following code:

```
$objZip = new COM("ZipLibrary");

$success = $objZip->UnlockComponent('Unlock code goes here');
if ($success != true)
{
    exit('Zip reg error!');
}


$success = $objZip->NewZip("./1.zip");

if ($success != true)
{
    exit('New Zip error!');
}

$success = $objZip->AppendString('Sample.txt', 'i love to test');
if ($success != true)
{
    exit('Add error!');
}


$success = $objZip->WriteZipAndClose();
if ($success != true)
{
    exit('Zip Write error!');
}   

$objZip = null;
unset($objZip);
```

but instead of saving files to current directory (where the PHP file is) it is saving the file to following directory:

```
c:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\apache\
```

How to get that file from that directory to current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move it using PHP's [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename) function:

```
rename('c:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\apache\1.zip', 'c:\path\to.zip');
```

But it's probably easier to get the COM component to save the zip to the right directory in the first place. What happens if you change `$objZip->NewZip("./1.zip");`, to something like `$objZip->NewZip(dirname(__FILE__) . '/1.zip');`?

Comment: wow! thanks.. a lot.. 
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/1.zip'
that's does the tricks :)